# Handling Connection Timeouts in Nokia S60 devices?

Tags: java-me, nokia, httpconnection

I have a thread which handles all the HTTP Connections to the server and there is another thread which updates the UI etc. I have a timeout logic implemented in the UI Thread which looks for some response and times it out (closes the connection and displays a notification to the user)

It works perfectly fine on Nokia Series 40 Devices, when the application goes out of range, however in Nokia Series 60 ( especially in E61,E71), the timeout never happens, the app hangs.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the whole JVM truly hang (as in no Java thread runs and no keypad notification can happen) or are we talking about a specific thread only?

Comment: I guess the whole JVM hangs, but on testing I have noticed, if you keep it for sometime, everything gets back to normal.

On a lighter note, if the user clicks no during connection check, the app still tries to connect. Any idea how to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out. I dont know whether it is the correct solution,While I was trying to timeout the connection, I was closing the connection from the UI thread, I guess this is why the UI thread froze.

Once I removed it everything is back to normal.